# Declarative chaining of knockout.js animations?

Tags: knockout.js

In trying to spice up a knockout.js UI with effects, I've found that I often have several sections that alternate based on a conditional. An example of this could be a details pane in a list view that displays instructions when no element is selected. This works great declarativly using the visible binding - but it falls short when you attempt to add animations to the mix, since there's no chaining of the show / hide animations.

I've simplified the animation knockout.js example here to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/yq5rS/

While I could probably hack something, I'm looking for a more idiomatic knockout.js way of doing this kind of chaining.

I've considered a few solutions:

- Having a container element with a custom binding that captures the conditional and which element to show in the on and off states.
- Having the "animation visible" binding dependent on both the conditional and a function that checks if the other element is hidden.

**Edit: To be clear, I want the fade out of one element to happen before the fade in of the other. Thanks Josh.**

Comment: You haven't really specified that you *want* to happen. Do you want all bound elements to hide before the other bound elements show? Do you want them to slide in/out at the same time, but smoothl?

Comment: This could be pure conjecture, but I believe he wants the animations to run serially. So they need to be ordered, one hides, then the other shows, or vice versa.

Comment: Indeed - exactly Josh. Edit done :-)

Comment: Yea I should have read the title huh. That would have cleared it up for me =)

Comment: The tricky part of this question in my mind is that the *order* of the animations has to change on every toggle. The only ways I can think to do this require some kind of linkage between them that is not elegant and not flexible... I'll post an answer if I can think of anything that isn't a total hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach creates a computed observable that looks to the boolean observable to determine which text to display.

Here's a working jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/yq5rS/10/

And here's a quick idea of the code

**Html**

```
<div class='liveExample'> 
    <p> 
        <label>
            <input type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: display' />
            Active?
        </label>
    </p>

    <p data-bind='fadeVisible: IsActive()'></p>    
</div>​
```

**Scripts**

```
var Model = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.display= ko.observable(false);
    self.IsActive = ko.computed(function() {
        if (self.display()) return "Active."
        return "Not active."
    }); 
};


ko.bindingHandlers.fadeVisible = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        $(element).hide().html(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)).fadeIn();
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        $(element).hide().html(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)).fadeIn();
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new Model ());​
```

**EDIT**

My initial response did not fade out, wait, and then fade back in.  Here is an updated fadeVisible binding handler

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fadeVisible = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        $(element).fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(element).html(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)).fadeIn();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Indeed, but this doesn't handle fade out of the content before fading in the new content...

Comment: the issue is with the jquery chaining.  $(element).fadeOut() does not lock so the .html() method occurs during the perceived fade out.  Here is a jsFiddle that resolves the issue with a setTimeout http://jsfiddle.net/yq5rS/12/

Comment: So here is a much safer jQuery way of "waiting" for the fadeOut() http://jsfiddle.net/yq5rS/13/

Answer (score 0):

One approach that might work for you is instead of displaying two element in the same space and toggling between them, stick with one element and use a custom binding that fades it out, swaps the content and then fades it back in. I think this would work nicely for your trivial case linked the jsfiddle.

Take a look at [Ryan Niemeyer's blog](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/reacting-to-changes-in-knockoutjs.html) and the linked [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QREf3/). The way he fade changes the total computed observable seems applicable to your swapping divs example.

I know you probably have more complicated tasks than just toggling between two divs... but there might be a way to extend the solution to a more general case. I'm no templates expert, but have you worked with them much? Particularly the `template { name: function() {} }` syntax for [dynamically changing templates](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/quick-tip-dynamically-changing.html)?

(I guess this officially makes me a Niemeyer Fanboy, but I'm not ashamed :-P )

Comment: I actually created a custom binding that used a container and swapped the 2 elements by fading out the container, swapping and then fading in the container as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/rasmuskl/QQxXw/ ... But then my problem became other observables, since the UI would update with the new values as the container was fading out, creating flicker :-( Complicated problem.